# pg_dump Isn't Reading ~/.pgpass

Tags: pg-dump

I'm trying to `bash script` a daily backup of my data using `pg_dump`.  I have a single entry in my `~/.pgpass` file, which is properly structured, proper `host`, `port`, `database`, `user` and `password`.

```
pg_dump -O -S user1ie -w -d dbname_p33 > /mnt/backups/server_n_pg_dbname_p33/server_n_pg_2022_07_19___10_44_backup.sql
```

The error:

```
pg_dump: error: connection to database "dbname_p33" failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "user1"
```

Since this is an `md5` connection, does that `.pgpass` entry need the `md5` version of the password?

I am unclear what I am doing wrong.  Nothing fancy happening here.

Anybody know how I can fix this?

Comment: Did you try connecting with `psql`?

Comment: @mustaccio Same `psql: error: fe_sendauth: no password supplied` for `psql -U user2 -w -d dbname_p33`.  The `-w` is meant to have it ask `~/.pgpass`, correct?

Comment: Just found that using `-w` forces a **no password used** scenario.  I assumed it looked into the `~/.pgpass` file, which it doesn't.  So taking that out makes this work for `psql`.  Also `-U` should be used.  I had `-S`.